# I get a post which I flagged before in review audit

Tags: bug, review, review-audits

I faced this already a couple of times.

In Late Answers or First Posts appears some stupid post that is not an answer.

I try to flag it, but it does not let me, because it seems that some time ago that was me who raised that flag already. It says that I've raised that flag.

If I press "No action needed". I get that scary notation "Look and Listen!"

I think the system can track that it was my flag.

Comment: Yeah, the whole testing this is just obnoxious...  I've gotten posts in a non-English language which I would just be able to translate and it gives me the "Look and Listen" or stuff I've reviewed before, or stuff that was closed an I immediately go and re-open... etc...  I hope at 20K it'll be gone forever!

Comment: @Fabby Heh. On the contrary. The more you review, the more audits you get.

Comment: @muru You're still having them???  I'm going to head over to meta.se and complain some there then!

Comment: There's a bigger problem: I got that stupid *Stop, Look and Listen* several times after pressing *No action needed* on perfectly acceptable answers that apparently were used as audit items just because they had negative score.  This is simply stupid.